# class does not export from dll when having std::map<int,std::ofstream> member

Tags: c++, dll, dictionary, fstream

Consider dll that exports class streamTest. Following code:

```
class  streamTest
{
public:
    TEST_API streamTest();
    TEST_API ~streamTest();

private:
    std::map<int,std::ofstream> streamMap;
};
```

compiles with no error and runs fine from application that links to dll, however following code:

```
class TEST_API streamTest
{
public:
    streamTest();
    streamTest();

private:
    std::map<int,std::ofstream> streamMap;
};
```

Gives warning and then error:

```
1>warning C4251: 'streamTest::streamMap' : class 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'streamTest'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=int,
1>              _Ty=std::ofstream
1>          ]
1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\fstream(1116): error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ios(176) : see declaration of 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ofstream(const std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
```

Why does it not compile, how can I provide dll interface for std::map? I have used std::map for objects other then std::ofstream in dll without any problem before. Please let me know what am I missing...

P.S. TEST_API is simply

```
#ifdef TEST_EXPORTS
#define TEST_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TEST_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ofstream` is not copyable. Exporting the class forces all methods of `map<int,std::ofstream>` to be instantiated - including those that attempt to copy the value.

You are using VC10, which doesn't support C++11 features. I don't believe you could store `ofstream` in a `map` there, export or no export.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense - +1. So, there is no work around? It works fine when I export all the methods but not the class itself though...

Comment: Do you have code that actually puts an `ofstream` instance into `streamMap`? I would be surprised if such code compiled. If you don't, then what is `streamMap` for?

Comment: Yes, this is just example representing the program. I put instances like streamMap.insert(key,std::ofstream(fname.c_str(),std::ios_base::binary));, works fine.

Comment: By the way, why does it work when I only export methods - is it because only methods of map I actually use are compiled in that case?

Comment: What do you know - VC10 does use rvalue references and move constructor when pushing the stream onto the map. I thought that started with VC12.

Comment: std::map<K, V> has many methods, some of them require that K and/or V be copyable, and others don't. Normally, the compiler wouldn't instantiate a method until it's actually used, so you are fine as long as you never call "bad" ones. But when you export the whole class, the compiler doesn't know which methods another module is going to call, so it needs to instantiate all of them, just in case - including all methods of that class' members.